# Azure diagnostics logs not copied to storage account

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-diagnostics

I am new to the Azure platform and simply trying to pull my IIS logs into my storage account.

When running locally and using the storage emulator, I can see the logs without issue.  However, when deploying the application, the log files are never created and the only container I see in blob storage is "vsdeploy".

I have followed the steps outlined here: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/diagnostics/

I have imported the diagnostics module in my ServiceDefinition.csdef

```
  ...<Imports>
         <Import moduleName="Diagnostics" />...
```

I have created a WebRole.cs class and configured directories for a scheduled transfer every two minutes.

```
  public class WebRole : RoleEntryPoint
{
    public override bool OnStart()
    {
        // For information on handling configuration changes
        // see the MSDN topic at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=166357.

        DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration diagConfig = DiagnosticMonitor.GetDefaultInitialConfiguration();


        diagConfig.Directories.ScheduledTransferPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2.0);  //IIS LOGS
        DiagnosticMonitor.Start("Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString", diagConfig);

        return base.OnStart();
    }
}
```

I have also verified my storage account connection string for cloud deployment is correct.

Still, when I deploy, nothing is ever created in the storage account.  What piece am I missing or not configuring correctly that is keeping me from my logs?

Thanks.

Comment: Kind of dumb question: Have you accessed the cloud application after you have deployed the application?